# CSS3 // calculate "real pixels" of an element after a matrix3d transform

Tags: css, matrix, transform

Let's say I zoom on an element with a matrix3d transform, how can one get the final dimension in pixels of this element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE

`Element.getBoundingClientRect()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

If you use jQuery, then `$(CSS selector)[0].getBoundingClientRect()`

will return `{height:?,width:?,top:?,left:?}` object data